# Sharing Rails Posts via social media

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, twitter, pinterest

Been looking for the best solution to sharing a rails post via social media: specifically, via Pinterest, Facebook, and Twitter.

In my opinion, dribbble does this better than anyone else. Unfortunately Idk if they're using a Gem or just jquery. Does anyone have a good solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you're still looking but this is what I use 
http://richonrails.com/articles/adding-social-sharing-buttons-to-your-rails-app